# What's the equivalent command of Eclipse EGit's “Synchronize Workspace”, for git-shell, or GUI like GitKraken?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, gitkraken

I have been using Eclipse EGit to manage my git repositories.

First I use the "Synchronize Workspace" function and make sure is there any conflicts, then I can decide whether I should pull the newer codes from remote or not.
[image: This picture shows the "Synchronize Workspace"]

Recently I am learning to use Git-shell or GUI like GitKraken to manage my git repositories. I know I can use Git Pull command to pull the newer codes, but I cannot find the equivalent command like "Synchronize Workspace", to peek that is there any difference between my local and remote repositories.

Is there any equivalent command of Eclipse EGit's "Synchronize Workspace", for git-shell, or GUI like GitKraken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem of (bad) git clients: they use vocabulary that obfuscate the git commands they execute. I suspect `git status`, that shows *which* files changed, or `git diff`, that shows *what*  was changed in these files, is what you're looking for.

EDIT:
After re-reading your question, I think you're looking for `git fetch`, that will update your local information about remotes, and `git status`, which will show you if your local branch is behind it's remote counterpart, like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Synchronize Workspace but you could use `git fetch --all` and then use `git status` to see if your local branch is in sync wit the remote branch.